# Spring Boot: `404 jsp page not found` when runned in remote server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, digital-ocean, filenotfoundexception

I have this simple project in Spring Boot. You can see my directory (it is just a default directory)

[image]

I've added this extra dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and this (to `applicaiton.properties` file):

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Everything works fine when I run it with `Intellij IDEA`. I can see the `home.jsp` page.

[image]

But when I upload and run the `jar` file in remote server (I am using https://www.digitalocean.com `ubuntu`) I get `404: not found` error:

[image]

Comment: I think you have got some error on console. Try to see the log file/console error if you can find something. Another thing, check if your target folder holds that jsp page too.

Comment: Can you share your config class and pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do some checks:

Check if:

1. Your application is deployed
2. WEB-INF folder is present

In addition, if you are using tomcat and your application is not getting start, check if Application.class is extending SpringBootServeltInitializer.

Remember that when you start application into Intellij, it starts with or without SpringBootServletInitializer but application need it in order to start in external Tomcat environment.

Comment: 1. My app is deployed, because I can receive jsons using rest requests. 2. Where should I check If WEB-INF is present? Inside my jar? Yes, my Application.class extends  SpringBootServletInitializer and I've added this method to it                          
 `@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PstestApplication.class);
    }`

Comment: In order to check if WEB-INF is present you need to unzip your jar and check if resources are there. 
Did you declared resources path into pom.xml? Check [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html, "Maven resources path")